# permission denied for certain git path

Tags: git, git-submodules, gerrit, permission-denied

I need to clone a submodule from a gerrit server to my local project. Here's a .gitmodule file that works:

```
[submodule "blah/blah/thing"]
  path = blah/blah/thing
  url = ssh://my_username@gerrit.somewhere.com/some-thing.git
```

Here's a .gitmodule file that I would like to work because it works for other team members:

```
[submodule "blah/blah/thing"]
  path = blah/blah/thing
  url = gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git
```

When I try to use the latter form, I get this error:

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'blah/blah/thing' (gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git) registered for path 'blah/blah/thing'

Cloning into 'blah/blah/thing'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git' into submodule path 'blah/blah/thing' failed
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I suppose this whole question could have been phrased without the submodule stuff. I really just need to know how to get git clone to authenticate that other form for the path, gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** put your username in the .gitmodule file.  This will cause all users to try and fetch the submodule using your username.  Instead follow the format in the second example, and specify your username in the `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gerrit.somewhere.com
    User my_username
```

(this assumes you are using ssh, which seems to be the case.  If you also use https, look into the .netrc file).

Comment: I can now git clone the submodule using gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git, but the submodule command still fails in the same way. Maybe my account in gerrit or the gerrit project is not configured correctly.

Comment: Never mind, after recloning the parent project and trying the submodule command again, it worked! Thank you @Brad!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're not logging in as the same user.  Try

```
url = my_username@gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git
```

where `my_username` is the same as in your `ssh:` url.

Comment: I would rather not put my username in the .gitmodule file since it is under change control.

Comment: @David But how would git find out username to login with?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it without putting the username in .gitmodule using host-based ssh configuration, etc.  But generally it's not a good thing to rely on a user name being a secret.

Comment: Oh, right, ssh configuration. Add `Host gerrit.somewhere.com <newline> User my_username` to `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work but it sure makes sense. This doesn't work either: "Host dev
    HostName dev.example.com
    Port 22000
    User fooey" from http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Comment: Never mind, I think that works but I made a mistake at first. As mentioned in another comment, now I can git clone gerrit.somewhere.com:some-thing.git, but the submodule command still fails in the same way.

Comment: Thank you gcbenison! Thank you kirelagin!